# Return Boolean Value as TRUE or FALSE in Select (PostgreSQL/pgAdmin)

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

In PostgreSQL (version 9.4, pgAdmin3), when doing select on a table with boolean column the data output shows 't' or 'f'.  I would like to cast/convert booleans as TRUE or FALSE without writing CASE statements or doing JOINS etc.

BTW, according to PostgreSQL own [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html) this behavior is not the SQL standard.

> The key words TRUE and FALSE are the preferred (SQL-compliant) usage.

PS: This happens only when using the SQL Editor in pgAdmin. Use pgAdmin object browser, drill down to same table, right-click, view data, View Top 100 rows, the same boolean column shows up as TRUE or FALSE, as expected/standard.

Comment: Whether it displays as "t"/"f" or "TRUE"/"FALSE" is simply a display issue. The boolean is returning the value of TRUE or FALSE (note, no quotes). How that gets represented on the display is up to that software. I would strongly suggest against trying to return a string value to get around a display issue here.

Comment: Correct - just a cosmetic issue.  I added pgAdmin to title of my question to clarify.  Also the display is specifically in pgAdmin SQL Editor.  So I guess it just a enhancement request in next release of pgAdmin - to be consistent with their own documentation and SQL standard ;-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If all you want to show is the literal `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can use the case statements like you had proposed. Since PostgreSQL treats `TRUE`, `true`, `yes`, `on`, `y`, `t` and `1` as true, I'd control how I'd want the output to look like.

Where clause can be written like:

```
select * from tablename where active
--or--
select * from tablename where active = true
```

(My recommendation is the same as PostgreSQL - use true)

When selecting, although there may be hesitation to use the case statements, I'd still recommend doing that to have control over your output string literal.

Your query would look like this:

```
select 
  case when active = TRUE then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as active_status,
  ...other columns...
from tablename
where active = TRUE;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4764d/1

```
create table test (id int, fullname varchar(100), active boolean);
insert into test values (1, 'test1', FALSE), (2, 'test2', TRUE), (3, 'test3', TRUE);

select
  id,
  fullname,
  case when active = TRUE then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as active_status
from test;

| id | fullname | active_status |
|----|----------|---------------|
|  1 |    test1 |         FALSE |
|  2 |    test2 |          TRUE |
|  3 |    test3 |          TRUE |
```

Comment: I am not a SQL guru.  Can we document a CASE statement to complete the answer just like you have shown with SELECT?  I did

Comment: Oh yeah, you bet. I've added an example

Comment: select *, CASE WHEN active IS TRUE THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END from tablename  (the comma after * is important)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. That comma between * and case is important.

Comment: This answer received a downvote. It would be nice to know why, and what can be improved; I'd happy to add improvements.

Answer (score 28):

A simple cast to `text` will do the job (unless you need upper case spelling):

```
SELECT true::text AS t, false::text AS f;

 t    | f
------+-------
 true | false
```

Else, the text representation depends on library and client you use to connect. JDBC for instance renders `boolean` values as 'true' / 'false' anyway:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0685e49d7d4ef849e73db5d11694479)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa214/1)</sub>

You will love this change in Postgres **9.5** (quoting the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html)):

> - Use assignment cast behavior for data type conversions in PL/pgSQL
>   assignments, rather than converting to and from text (Tom Lane)
>
> This change causes **conversions of Booleans to strings to produce `true`
> or `false`, not `t` or `f`**. Other type conversions may succeed in more cases
> than before; for example, assigning a numeric value `3.9` to an integer
> variable will now assign `4` rather than failing. If no assignment-grade
> cast is defined for the particular source and destination types,
> PL/pgSQL will fall back to its old I/O conversion behavior.

Bold emphasis mine.