# Replace an entire field value in a file using awk or other

Tags: bash, postgresql, awk, monetdb

I have an export from postgresql table with multiple fields, including boolean (exported by postgresql as `t` and `f` character), and I need to import it in another database (monetdb) that won't understand t/f as bool values.

(**EDIT** removed spaces to reflect true file aspect and avoid angry comments - previously there was spaces displayed)

```
id|val_str|bool_1|bool2|bool_3|bool4|
1|help|t|t|f|t|
2|test|f|t|f|f|
...
```

As I cannot replace all occurence of `t`/`f` I need to integrate the field separator in my pattern.
I tried to use `awk` to replace fields `t` with `TRUE` and `f` with `FALSE`:

```
awk -F'|' '{gsub(/\|t\|/, "|TRUE|"); gsub(/\|f\|/, "|FALSE|"); print;}'
```

This is working partially, as consecutive fields with a same value (`|t|t|`) will have only the first occurrence replaced (`|TRUE|t|` - as 2nd occurence is in fact `t|` and not `|t|`).

```
id|val_str|bool_1|bool2|bool_3|bool4|
1|help|TRUE|t|FALSE|TRUE|
2|test|FALSE|TRUE|FALSE|f|
...
```

Table has ~450 columns so I can't really specify the list of columns to be replaced, nor work in postgres to 'transform' boolean columns (I could but ...).

I could run the `gsub()` twice, but I was looking for more elegant way to match the entire field content for all fields.

`gsub(/^t$/, ...)` is not helping either as we are in the middle of a line most of the time.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility to make postgresql output the desired format? I would have expected a flag or some other parameter making it easy, it looks like [there's no such thing but it's still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959507/output-yes-no-instead-of-t-f-for-boolean-data-type-in-postgresql).

Comment: What does `[Original file has no space]` mean? If the sample input you posted isn't the same format as your real data then, obviously, fix that so it is or you'll get a more complicated solution than necessary or one that just doesn't work and either way will be wasting peoples time. If that's just a completely irrelevant statement then get rid of it.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Table has ~450 columns so I can't really specify the list of columns
>   to be replaced, nor work in postgres to 'transform' boolean columns (I
>   could but ...).

You can **let Postgres do the work for you**. Basic query to produce the `SELECT` list:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(CASE WHEN atttypid = 'bool'::regtype
                       THEN quote_ident(attname) || '::text'
                       ELSE quote_ident(attname) END, ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'mytable'::regclass  -- provide table name here
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped;
```

Produces a string of the form:

```sql
col1, "CoL 2", bool1::text, "Bool 2"::text
```

All identifiers are escaped properly. Columns are in default order. Copy and execute it. Use `COPY` to export to file. (Or `\copy` in psql.) Performance is about the same as exporting a plain table. If you don't need upper case omit `upper()`.

Why is a simple cast to `text` enough?

- [Return Boolean Value as TRUE or FALSE in Select (PostgreSQL/pgAdmin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440068/return-boolean-value-as-true-or-false-in-select-postgresql-pgadmin/34442407#34442407)

About `regclass` and escaping identifiers properly:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

If you need a complete statement with `TRUE` / `FALSE` / `NULL` in upper case, standard SQL cast notation (without colons `::`), still original column names and maybe a schema-qualified tablename:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT '
     || string_agg(CASE WHEN atttypid = 'bool'::regtype
                        THEN format('upper(cast(%1$I AS text)) AS %1$I', attname)
                        ELSE quote_ident(attname) END, ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
     || ' FROM myschema.mytable;'           -- provide table name twice now
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped;
```

Produces a complete statement of the form:

```sql
SELECT col1, "CoL 2", upper(cast(bool1 AS text) AS bool1, upper(cast("Bool 2" AS text)) AS "Bool 2" FROM myschema.mytable;
```

Comment: "I could but ..." => now I can! DBeaver (JDBC client) is complaining about an "unexepected symbol (:)", but with `psql` it is fine, except that I need to add the column name: `THEN 'upper(' || quote_ident(attname) || '::text) AS ' || quote_ident(attname)` to have the right column name. Or remove `upper`.

Comment: @ant1j: I wasn't sure you need upper case and / or original column names. As for the short cast notation (`col::text`), you can replace it with SQL standard syntax `cast(col AS text)`. Consider updates above.

Comment: short cast notation is fine for DBeaver normally, I don't know why he's complaining on this one... thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

if `perl` is okay, you can use lookarounds:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
id |  val_str  | bool_1 | bool2  | bool_3 | bool4  | 
1  |    help   |   t    |   t    |   f    |   t    |
2  |    test   |   f    |   t    |   f    |   f    | 

$ perl -pe 's/\|\K\h*t\h*(?=\|)/  TRUE  /g; s/\|\K\h*f\h*(?=\|)/  FALSE /g' ip.txt 
id |  val_str  | bool_1 | bool2  | bool_3 | bool4  | 
1  |    help   |  TRUE  |  TRUE  |  FALSE |  TRUE  |
2  |    test   |  FALSE |  TRUE  |  FALSE |  FALSE |
```

- `\|\K` positive lookbehind to match `|`
- `\h*` optional horizontal space, remove if not actually present in input
- `(?=\|)` positive lookahead to match `|`

Can also use looping with `sed`. Tested on `GNU sed 4.2.2`, syntax may vary with other implementations

```
$ sed ':a s/| *t *|/|  TRUE  |/;ta; :b s/| *f *|/|  FALSE |/;tb' ip.txt 
id |  val_str  | bool_1 | bool2  | bool_3 | bool4  | 
1  |    help   |  TRUE  |  TRUE  |  FALSE |  TRUE  |
2  |    test   |  FALSE |  TRUE  |  FALSE |  FALSE |
```

- `:a` label
- `s/| *t *|/|  TRUE  |/` substitute command
- `ta` branch to label `a` as long as substitute command succeeds
- similarly for `:b`

With no spaces in input

```
perl -pe 's/\|\Kt(?=\|)/TRUE/g; s/\|\Kf(?=\|)/FALSE/g' ip.txt 
sed ':a s/|t|/|TRUE|/;ta; :b s/|f|/|FALSE|/;tb' ip.txt 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="t"){$i="TRUE"} if($i=="f"){$i="FALSE"}} print}' ip.txt
```

Comment: source file has no space in fact. Looks good to me. Not familiar with perl but I guess I can send output to pipe STDOUT ?

Comment: yes this is just like any other command... output can be piped

Comment: There it is again - `source file has no space in fact.`. Sounds like you're asking us to help you solve a problem that (due to the white space) is harder to solve than the much simpler problem you really have.

Comment: and now I also have a solution in case of spaces... thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (based on your comments) that your input file actually doesn't look like the sample you posted but instead looks like this:

```
$ cat file
id|val_str|bool_1|bool2|bool_3|bool4|
1|help|t|t|f|t|
2|test|f|t|f|f|
```

then all you need is:

```
$ awk '{while(gsub(/\|t\|/,"|TRUE|")); while(gsub(/\|f\|/,"|FALSE|"));}1' file
id|val_str|bool_1|bool2|bool_3|bool4|
1|help|TRUE|TRUE|FALSE|TRUE|
2|test|FALSE|TRUE|FALSE|FALSE|
```

with the general solution for N replacement strings being:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{m["f"]="FALSE"; m["t"]="TRUE"} {for (k in m) while(gsub("\\|"k"\\|","|"m[k]"|"));} 1' file
id|val_str|bool_1|bool2|bool_3|bool4|
1|help|TRUE|TRUE|FALSE|TRUE|
2|test|FALSE|TRUE|FALSE|FALSE|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`, it`s standard.

`sed 's/| *t  */| TRUE /g;s/| *f  */| FALSE /g'`

This tells `sed` to substitute every substring that begins with a pipe character, an unknown number of spaces (maybe zero), `t` and a space followed by an unknown number of spaces with `| TRUE`; same with `f`.

Pipe the output through `column -t` if line lengths get messed up.

Comment: this will not work for all cases... for example: `echo 'abc| t 12| t |' | sed 's/| *t  */| TRUE /g'`

Comment: What exactly *is* `t 12`?

Comment: hypothetical column data... your solution doesn't check `|` boundary on both sides

Comment: @Sundeep the only data that can contain spaces here is a string. Strings generally begin with a quote, thus mismatching the regex. And BTW, your solution also doesn\`t check for something like that: `| "HELLO IMMA STRING! | t |" |`

Comment: that is true.. if `|` cannot be safely used as delimiter, using regex will be bad idea

Comment: …But really, I don`t think OP\`s case is *that* convoluted. And that made me keep my regex as simple as possible =)