# Replace single zeros of a tab-separated-values file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How do I replace single zeros (`0`) with string `NA` in a tab-separated-values file?

Suppose I have the table:

```
0\t0.15\t0t\8.05\t0\t0\t0.15\7.0306\n
5\t0.18\t0\8.05\t0\t0\t0.5t\50\n
1\t15\t0205\t0\t0.16\t200t\40.90\n
```

I would like to get:

```
NA\t0.15\NAt\8.05\tNA\tNA\t0.15t\7.0306\n
5\t0.18\tNA\8.05\tNA\tNA\t0.5t\50\n
1\t15\t0205\tNA\t0.16\t200t\40.90\n
```

That is, I would like to match the null measures of the data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` enables a robust, portable solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i=="0") {$i="NA"} }; print}' file
```

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}` tells `awk` - before input processing begins (`BEGIN`) -
  to split *input* lines into fields by tab characters (`FS="\t"`) and to also separate them by tab characters on *output* (`OFS="\t"`).

  - Reserved variable `FS` is the [input] **f**ield **s**eparator; `OFS` is the **o**utput **f**ield **s**eparator.
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)` loops over all input fields (`NF` is the count of input fields), resulting from splitting each input line by tabs.

  - `if ($i=="0") {$i="NA"}` tests each field for being identical to string `0` and, if so, replaces that field (`$i`) with string `NA`.
  - On *assigning* to a field, the input line at hand is implicitly *rebuilt* from the (modified) field values, using the value of `OFS` as the separator.
- `print` simply prints the (potentially modified) input line at hand.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(\t)*\b0\b(\t)/\1NA\2/g;ta;' file
```

Using backreference, this replace `0` eventually preceded of followed by a tab(`\t`) with `NA` and captured tab.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU or OSX sed for -E for EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|\t)0(\t|$)/\1NA\2/g; s/(^|\t)0(\t|$)/\1NA\2/g' file
NA      0.15    NA      8.05    NA      NA      0.15    7.0306
5       0.18    NA      8.05    NA      NA      0.5     50
1       15      NA      205     NA      0.16    200     40.90
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908420/1745001 for why it takes 2 passes.